# (.NET) Doing an Action when any exception is thrown

Tags: c#, .net, exception, azure-functions

Is there an effective way to essentially do something else when any exception is thrown in .NET 6?

Specifically, this is using Azure Functions v4 if that helps.

Essentially, If I have a function that throws due to a Null Reference Exception, is it possible to send an HTTP request before killing the program?

IE:

C#

```
public async Task<Exception> SendErrorMessage(Exception ex)
{
    _httpClient.PostAsync("https://myloggingurl.com/", new StringContent(ex.Message));
    return ex;
}
```

Essentially writing a solution that throws all exceptions through this method.

Comment: Put a try catch for the exceptoin then call sendErrorMessage with await and then throw.

Comment: After reading the two answers below, and seeing them downvoted, I am left wondering what the actual question is...? I don't think it is clear the way it is currently written.

Answer (score 0):

Register for the [AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.unhandledexception?view=net-7.0).

This is a platform agnostic .Net event.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
public async Task<Exception> SendErrorMessage(Exception ex)
        {
            try
            {
                _httpClient.PostAsync("https://myloggingurl.com/", new StringContent(ex.Message));
            }
            catch
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I am attempting to catch EVERY exception the program throws, Post this HTTP request, then throw the same exception.

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem, and you should only `throw ex`; instead of just `throw;` when you want to destroy the stack trace. Which is almost never.

Comment: @Jonathan, this is not what I am looking for unfortunately. this function is really just an example, I am aware with this function that you can run: throw await SendErrorMessage(new Exception()); to throw it. I want to wrap ALL exceptions with this.